# Random number example from Stroustrup has compilation error

Tags: c++

I'm using this random number example from Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed Page 1182. The compiler is reporting an error on the line with `auto`, stating that auto cannot be used with non-static members of classes.  I'm confused on what the type of this bind results in.  Does anyone know how to resolve the error so the random number generator can be used?

```
#include <random>
using namespace std;

class Rand_int {
public: // added
    Rand_int(int lo, int hi) : p{lo,hi} { }
    int operator()() const { return r(); }
private:
    uniform_int_distribution<>::param_type p;
    auto r = bind(uniform_int_distribution<>{p},default_random_engine{});
};

int main()
{
    Rand_int ri {0,10};
    int pz = ri();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation error:

```
clang++ -Wall -std=c++11 -pedantic test252.cc && ./a.out
test252.cc:11:5: error: 'auto' not allowed in non-static class member
    auto r = bind(uniform_int_distribution<>{p},default_random_e...
    ^~~~
```

Comment: use c++14 to compile

Comment: The book was written to conform to the C++11 standard.

Comment: This is invalid in any C++ standard to date. I think the example was probably devised outside a class and the re-written.

Comment: It could just be errata, the `public` line was missing and there is lots of unlisted errata in this book.

Comment: I changed the question to "does anyone know how to resolve this error so the random number generator an be used?"

Comment: @Bathsheba - It can't be allowed. Default member initializers are ignored when initializing said member in a member initializer list. What type should the member have then? It's near impossible to do static typing intuitively and consistently while still allowing for all those initialization forms.

Comment: Looks like an oversight in the book.  Adapt from the example for `class Rand_double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `auto` for the type of a non-static member of a class, so the code example is wrong.

Instead, you can do:

```
class Rand_int {
  private:
    std::function<int()> r = bind(uniform_int_distribution<>{p},default_random_engine{});
  // ...
};
```

This converts the return type of `std::bind` to a void function returning an int, which is the desired behavior.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d7Kdnc).

Comment: I thought bind creates a function that is passed an argument, `default_random_engine()` in this case, yet `int()` function type?

Comment: No, `bind` binds the `default_random_engine` argument precisely so it's callable with no arguments. See how it's being used in `operator()`.